# Jenkins file GROOVY error -- java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method tokenize() on null object

Tags: jenkins, groovy, nullpointerexception

I am facing one issue while building my project in Jenkins.

Actually recently we have migrated our code from GITLAB to GITHUB.
Earlier we were using variables by which are directly available in GITLAB.
But now we are accessing the Webhook data by post content parameter in Jenkins.
When we are pushing the code from IDE to GITHUB my pipeline is working fine.
But when I am running my pipeline using build with parameter.
This line of code is creating issue

```
env.gitLabSourceBranch = env.GIT_BRANCH.tokenize('/')[2]
```

`env.GIT_BRANCH` is coming from the post Webhook trigger.

I want a solution that when we trigger pipeline as build with parameter it should take the GITBRANCH value as null and bypass this firstline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want a solution that when we trigger pipeline as build with parameter it should take the GITBRANCH value as null and bypass this firstline.

Try this:

```
env.gitLabSourceBranch = env.GIT_BRANCH ? env.GIT_BRANCH.tokenize('/')[2] : null
```

Comment: Thank you soo much.
It worked .
Can you please explain what the above syntax is doing.
Hopefully It will take every time the actual value from Webhook at the time of git push.
And the null at general build with parameter.

Comment: @ankitSrivastava if env.GIT_BRANCH is not null will try to tokenize it, otherwise the null value  will be taken.